# using real world images to add textures to cad models

Tags: rendering, texturing, file-format, photorealism, resolution

I have a 3d scanner that can also record texture, however if i have it set up to a resolution that provides the accuracy that i'm looking for then the file sizes are simply too big. Parts that i am scanning range from 0.5m to about 15m. I would like to use textured 3d models for some augmented reality purposes, but at the moment i can't because of the file size. In the scanner software the texture is stored as a .bmp file. The texture i can only export as a .bmp file but the mesh i can export in various formats. When exporting in some formats the .bmp file is automatically also exported as well as a .mtl file for mapping the texture to the mesh. Is there a format or way in blender that i can load a model with the texture and then replace the mesh with a reverse engineered cad model (significantly smaller) and also at the same time massively reduce the file size of the .bmp file? To give an example a merged and textured scan of a "dome-shaped" component with a base diameter of about 3m and a height of about 1.5m is about 16gb of which the .bmp file is approximately 8gb. I need to get to a textured 3d model that is of a file size that is hopefully in the megabyte range rather than gigabytes. I am also open to suggestions how i might be able to use blender to load a reverse engineered model and add texture by wrapping the model with a few pictures if that is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately Blender is not yet very capable in dealing with point clouds from laser scanners. However CloudCompare (open source) can do some crazy things. Documentation is pretty sparse but the features are really simple to use, you just have to understand where to click. Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS3Krxcy2j0 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m43usERF33M or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcrcoocYSlU

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no experience in 3D scanning and .mtl files. But for the file size of the .bmp file: as soon as you have a model in Blender and the image is somehow mapped onto it, I guess there is an _Image Texture_ node somewhere in the material using the bitmap. It should be no problem to replace the .bmp file in the node with some other file format like PNG, JPG, TIF etc. which is significantly smaller than BMP. If you use for example IrfanView to create a JPG, it is usually a much much smaller file than a BMP or even a JPG saved by Photoshop while still having a good quality.